# InputStream in.read() behaving differently than expected

Tags: java, sockets, networking, inputstream

I am trying to transfer a text file to another server using TCP and it is behaving differently than expected. The code sending the data is:

```
        System.out.println("sending file name...");
        String outputFileNameWithDelimiter = outputFileName + "\r\n"; //These 4 lines send the fileName with the delimiter
        byte[] fileNameData = outputFileNameWithDelimiter.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        outToCompression.write(fileNameData, 0, fileNameData.length);
        outToCompression.flush();

        System.out.println("sending content...");
        System.out.println(new String(buffer, dataBegin, dataEnd-dataBegin));
        outToCompression.write(buffer, dataBegin, dataEnd-dataBegin); //send the content
        outToCompression.flush();

        System.out.println("sending magic String...");
        byte[] magicStringData = "--------MagicStringCSE283Miami".getBytes("US-ASCII"); //sends the magic string to tell Compression server the data being sent is done
        outToCompression.write(magicStringData, 0, magicStringData.length);
        outToCompression.flush();
```

Because this is TCP and you can't send discrete packets like in UDP, I expected all of the data to be in the input stream and I could just use delimiters to separate the file name, content, and ending string and then each in.read() would just give me the next subsequent amount of data.

Instead this is the data I am getting on each read:

```
On the first in.read() byteBuffer appears to only have "fileName\r\n". 
On the second in.read() byteBuffer still has the same information. 
On the third in.read() byteBuffer now holds the content I sent. 
On the fourth in.read() byteBuffer holds the content I sent minus a few letters.
On the fifth in.read() I get the magicString + part of  the message.
```

I am flushing on every send from the Webserver, but input streams don't seem to implement flushable.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

EDIT:
This is how I am reading things in. Basically this in  a loop then writing to a file.

```
 in.read(byteBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
```

Comment: Can you show how you're reading from `in` on the client side? I have a strong suspicion that you're not checking the return value of `in.read()` (the number of bytes actually read from the stream).

Comment: I'm not, but why would checking that matter? Wouldn't that just let me debug it (I feel like seeing that the in.read() is the problem is what seeing the count would be useful for), not explain why it is acting as such? Posting the code now.

Comment: I would not send a magic string but the length beforehand if you know it. And you should treat tcp as a stream not as packets (i.e. the input might have different chunks than the received reads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expectation is that read will fill the buffer, or receive exactly what was sent by a single `write()` by the peer, it is your expectation that is at fault here, not `read().` it isn't specified to transfer more than one byte at a time, and there is no guarantee about preserving write boundaries.

It is quite impossible to write correct code without storing the result of `read()` into a variable.

Comment: @Eckes Only when you supply a zero length. Impossible otherwise, as the underlying `recv()` won't do it either.

Comment: hm probably, I dont recall the situation when I had to handle 0. (However the POSIX definition of read() explicitly defines 0 byte reads (on STREAMS at least): ["How read() handles zero-byte STREAMS messages is determined by the current read mode setting..."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html). (In Java you cant sent those.)

Comment: @eckes You can't send a zero-length segment in TCP by any means. It is impossible. *Ergo* you can't receive them either. You can send zero-length datagrams.

Comment: yes, I guess it was a TLS socket then. Cant remeber the details :-/

Answer (score 0):

When you read from an `InputStream`, you're giving it a byte array to write into (and optionally an offset and a maximum amount to read). `InputStream` makes no guarantees that the array will be filled with fresh data. The return value is the number of bytes that was actually read into it.

What's happening in your example is this:

- The first TCP packet comes in with `"fileName\r\n"`, gets written into your buffer, everything fine so far.
- You call `read()` again, but the next packet hasn't arrived yet. <del>`read()` will have returned `0`, because it didn't want to block until data arrived. So the buffer still contains `"fileName\r\n"`</del>. Edit: as pointed out, `read()` always blocks until it reads at least one byte. Don't really know why the buffer didn't change then.
- On the third read, the content has arrived.
- The first bit of the content gets overwritten with the second part of the message, the last bit still contains part of the old message (I think that's what you meant).
- etc., you get the idea

You need to check the return value, wait for the data to arrive, and only use as much of the buffer as was written by the last `read()`.

Comment: `InputStream.read()` blocks until at least one byte is available or end of stream or an exception. The only way it can return zero is if you supply a zero length to read into. It doesn't return zero if there is no data. Only a non-blocking channel read can do that.

Comment: At least in oder java it could return 0 bytes (especially when the sender was sending 0-byte sized segments). I know it has changed in the documentation but I would not depend on it (in fact when you handle partial reads you can as well handle 0 reads).

Comment: @eckes No it can't. You are mistaken. It hasnt' changed in the documentation, which I've been reading since 1997, and it wasn't different in older versions of Java.